# Linking a CSS file with version number for cache busting

Tags: html, css

Css file name is: `style.css`

The link inside of html: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=1">`

I tried this but it is not working. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by _it's not working_?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. “Not working” is not a proper problem description. Explain what exactly happens, and what you have done so far to try and find the error.

Comment: whenever I made a change in my css file or js file, the browsers are storing cache, to solve that problem I tried to add versions to the css file like above but it is not working?

Comment: Do you change version every time you made a change in your css?

Comment: how to add the version in css file...?

Comment: If you made a second change, you have to add <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=2">

Comment: @Sfili_81 when I tried this <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=2">  but my css file is not rendering.

Comment: [read this](https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/)

Answer (score 0):

These are usually to make sure that the browser gets a new version when the site gets updated with a new version, e.g. as part of our build process we'd have something like this:

```
style.css?v=buildnumber
```

So, you can try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Comment: In which file I have to manage this " style.css?v=buildnumber "

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding files via JavaScript while testing with random version to avoid caching.

Also, if the file can not be rendered, try adding 'type="text/css"' to the tag.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var head = document.querySelector('head');
  head.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v='+Math.random()+'" type="text/css">';
});
```